# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre enfrentar y enfrentarse?

Tags: reflexivos

Por favor explíquenme la diferencia entre las dos frases:

> *desafíos a los que nos enfrentamos*

vs

> *desafíos que enfrentamos*

Una frase usa el verbo *enfrentar**se*** y la otra, *enfrentar*.

¿Son absolutamente iguales o hay una diferencia sutil en el significado?

Comment: enfrentarse es la forma pronominal del verbo enfrentar, y es solo usado para generar reflexividad 

pero, en tu ejemplo en ningún caso veo el uso del reflexivo....,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como se ve en [la respuesta de Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27492/14627), las dos formas del verbo (simple y pronominal) son equivalentes según el diccionario.

Sin embargo, a nivel pragmático (o sea, en el uso real) puede haber diferentes connotaciones. Personalmente el verbo *enfrentar* en su forma simple me resulta más "activo" que en la forma pronominal *enfrentarse*.

Por ejemplo, si digo

> *Alice enfrentó a Bob.*

la frase me sugiere que Alice fue a buscar a Bob para atacarlo, criticarlo, etc., o que Alice respondió activamente a una agresión de Bob.

En cambio,

> *Alice se enfrentó con Bob.*

me sugiere que Alice se vio frente a Bob en una situación agresiva y decidió responderle, o al menos quedarse en su lugar.

Hay verbos que son opcionalmente pronominales y que expresan acciones diferentes según si aparece el pronombre o no. Típicamente la forma simple es transitiva y su objeto directo indica el destinatario de una acción del sujeto, mientras que la forma pronominal es intransitiva y se refiere a un cambio de actitud del sujeto. Por ejemplo:

- *Alice enojó a Bob.* vs. *Alice se enojó (con Bob).*
- *Alice disculpó a Bob.* vs. *Alice se disculpó (con Bob).*

Aunque *enfrentar* no cambia de significado de esta manera entre sus formas simple y pronominal, es posible que estos otros verbos, donde la forma simple es más "activa" que la pronominal, influya en la diferencia de connotación que se le da a *enfrentar* con *enfrentarse*.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. En el ejemplo de la pregunta, la frase pronominal me da la idea de que tenemos esos desafíos delante y tenemos que hacer algo con ellos; la segunda, que efectivamente estamos haciendo algo con los desafíos.

Answer (score 4):

> Una frase usa el verbo enfrentar**se** y la otra, enfrentar.

No hay diferencia. Según el DRAE [enfrentar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FJ4BrX4) tiene tres acepciones y en las tres encontramos las notas "U. t. c. prnl." (usado también como pronominal).

[image]

Por lo tanto, parece que en todas sus acepciones "enfrentar" puede ser usado como pronominal y llevar el reflexivo.

Podrías decir también

> desafíos a los que ellos **se** enfrentan
>
> desafíos que enfrentan

Incluir la parte de "[a los que / a los cuales] (alguien se enfrenta)" obliga a incluir el pronombre reflexivo.

Comment: Tengo que mejorar un poco esta respuesta en su última parte, pues no estoy del todo seguro porqué el reflexivo es necesario. Entiendo que tiene que ver con clarificar el sujeto/CD de ese verbo pronominal al introducir la frase subordinada "a los que <<sujeto de enfrentar>>", pero tengo que investigar un poco más y poner algunas fuentes y ejemplos adecuados. Esta respuesta está incompleta.

Comment: Más allá de la definición, a nivel pragmático me parece que el sujeto de *enfrentarse* suena levemente más pasivo que el de *enfrentar*, aunque depende del contexto.

Answer (score 1):

En España, lo normal es usar el reflexivo: enfrentarse (el que habla) a algo. De otro modo, damos a entender que nosotros quedamos al margen. Así, estaría bien: enfrentamos a Juan con Pedro, o a Juan contra Pedro. Si no usamos el reflexivo, quizá lo conveniente sería emplear el verbo afrontar: afrontamos (no "enfrentamos") una dificultad. En España, lo vemos como un americanismo, que allá estará bien, pero aquí suena raro. Algo similar ocurre con "colapsar". Si la acción queda en el sujeto, se usa el reflexivo.