# nadie que se nos enfrente - meaning of "se"

Tags: pronombres

I have heard the following sentence in the Narcos TV series:

> Ya no queda nadie que se nos enfrente.

I have already read [All about datives, or: What's that funny "le" or "me" doing in there?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there), but I'm not sure about the purpose of the reflexive pronoun in this sentence. Is it an ethical dative?  If so, how exactly is "nobody" concerned or involved in challenging us? It is related to the fact that whoever tries may get beaten/killed?

Comment: @fedorqui AFAIK there is already a generic question about this subject: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/all-about-datives-or-whats-that-funny-le-or-me-doing-in-there . Unfortunately, reading it is not enough to understand the meaning of the object/reflexive pronoun in any sentence, at least to me. I assume that other non native speakers have the same problem and that my specific questions will also be useful to them.

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27491/cuál-es-la-diferencia-entre-enfrentar-y-enfrentarse

Comment: I think there is a "no" missing. To be correct, the sentence should read as follows: *Ya **no** nos queda nadie que se nos enfrente.*

Comment: @Gustavson the line is "ya no queda nadie...", it was a typo. I have fixed it.

Comment: Great catch from @aris.  I had a slip of the finger when trying to vote to close as duplicate with aris's find.  I accidentally voted to close for lack of effort (which would have been a valid reason, in my opinion, if aris hadn't found the dupe).  A dictionary definition and link are needed.  We sometimes turn a blind eye regarding this requirement for raw beginners who are just getting started with the site but OP does not fall in that category.